# finding exact strings with sql like statement

Tags: sql-server

I have the following statement

```
SELECT *
FROM   Delivery_Note this_
WHERE  mycol like '%[126]%'
```

I've noticed this also returns rows that contain [123]. What is the best way to find exact matching in a string.

*edit*
I appreciate this is not an efficient query. There a few other reasons for this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Brackets specify a range when used with `LIKE`. You can use the `ESCAPE` keyword.

```
WHERE mycol LIKE '%\[126\]%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Of course if you are trying to match an exact string, you don't need `LIKE`, or you can drop the `%` characters and `LIKE` will behave like `=` (this makes it flexible to pass in wildcards or exact matches to a parameter).